# How to convert FutureBuilder into StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-hive, flutter-streambuilder

I made a widget that should automatically update if there are changes to the Hive database value. I have just learned that Futures only get the value once, so I need a Stream to constantly monitor changes. Now, how can I use StreamBuilder with my Hive database?

**Here is my code:**
This should become a Stream Builder so that the Text() will get update whenever there are changes in the value of .getUserNickname.

```
FutureBuilder(
   future: UserInformationController.getUserNickname(),
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      return InkWell(
         onTap: () {
            openDialog();
         },
         child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
               Column(
                  children: [
                     Text(
                        language == "Filipino" ? "Palitan ang iyong palayaw" :
                           "Change your nickname",
                            style: kSettingSubheaderText(),),
                     Text(snapshot.hasData == true ? snapshot.data : "（‐＾▽＾‐）",
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,)
                    ],
                 ),
               const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_rounded)
            ],
         ),
      );
   }
),
```

## This is the UserInformationController where it takes the data:

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

class UserInformationController{
  static Future<void> setUserNickname(String nickname) async {
    var userInformationBox = await Hive.openBox('userInformationBox');
    await userInformationBox.put('userNickname', nickname);
  }

  static Future<String> getUserNickname() async {
    var userInformationBox = Hive.box('userInformationBox');
    return await userInformationBox.get('userNickname');
  }
}
```

Thank you so much!